# How to check validity for username and password from text file

Tags: java

I want to read inside of my text file and match the accountNumber and pin that user inputs in the login page.

- This is my text file format

  ```
  0,admin,lastAdmin,1122334455,123456.
  ```

  0 stands for id.

  admin stands for name.

  lastAdmin stands form lastName.

  1122334455 stand for accountNumber.

  123456 stands for pin.
- And this is my code that have errors

  ```
  package atm;

  import java.io.BufferedReader;

  import java.io.FileInputStream;

  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Login {

      public void verifyLogin(){
          String accountNumber;
          String pin;
          Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);

          try{
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myDataBase.txt");
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

              String line;
              while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null ){
                String[] lineSpliter = line.split(",");
                if (accountNumber.equals(accountNumber) && pin.equals(pin)){
                    br.readLine(lineSpliter[6] + ',' +lineSpliter[8]);
                }
              }
          }
      catch (Exception e){
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: what are the errors you are getting can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Do not store PIN or any other password as plain text.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki can you complete my code ?

Comment: @Blank Your code makes no sense e.g. `accountNumber.equals(accountNumber)`. Self is equal to self but variable has to be initialized.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki yes but my professor want to save the data in text file.

Comment: you need to compare the lines you read in to presumably something the user does? you should look at taking input from a user if this the case

Comment: @dave yes. i exactly i want is. when user  input the accountNumber and pin the code will read the database text file and compare it.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki name and pin is no default value.

Comment: @Blank it's pretty much the answer all you need to is figure how to get a user to input something look at scanner for this there are loads of examples on this site and replace name and pin with what you read in

Comment: @dave br.readLine(lineSpliter[6] + ',' +lineSpliter[8]); in this line 
the readLine still markable in redline.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp read up on this. These will help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the row identified by `name` and compare `pin`:

```
String name = "admin";
String pin = "123456";
Path path = Path.of("myDatabase.txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
    String[] row = reader.lines()
            .map(s -> s.split(","))
            .filter(r -> r[1].equals(name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Name not found"));
    if (row[4].equals(pin)) {
        System.out.println("Correct pin");
    }
}
```